# Getting external markers for a new google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to create an instance of a Google map that uses markers from an external Google Map. More specifically I need to grab all the markers from the "source map", run some algorithms and filtering and them add them to my newly created Google Map.

I've tried searching both the Google Maps API and forums for clues, but most of them are about getting markers from the current map, and not externally.

Do I need to use the KML source somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just load the coordinates you need from an external source and use that to populate a markers array?

Comment: Because I don't have access to the external source. The problem I'm having is just reading the generated .KML file in jQuery. I can read it without any problems if it's a local file, but I need to get a new file every time to see recent changes.

Comment: If it is a source you work with, can you not ask them to provide a file for you?