# How to get external Google Maps data as KML out of the HttpResponse directly into Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, kml, httpresponse

I'm working on a project where I have to grab data (markers etc.) from several external Google Maps maps. I'm writing this on the client-side in Javascript and in theory it's all working as it should, but the problem is that when I call the KML generation url for each map using .get() or .ajax() it processes the HttpGet-request, and returns the .KML file.. but it places it in the "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.KML" attribute of the HttpResponse.

Is there a way to get that file out of there with JS /jQuery? Reading the file itself is no problem, it's getting it out of that ResponseHeader that is the problem since I can't save it locally on the server.

Any ideas? Would greatly appreciate your insight!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting external markers for a new google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230068/getting-external-markers-for-a-new-google-map)

Comment: perhaps you should just update your original question.

Comment: I thought about it, but while the topics are (very) related, this is actually a different question (in my opinion), as this is about retrieving a file from a certain HttpResponse field

Comment: You still haven't provided enough details (IMO) to answer the question.  What are the external Google Maps maps?  Do you have permission to scrape the data?  Why doesn't KmlLayer just work?

Comment: As far as I can tell KmlLayer copies the data directly over to the map, which is no good because I need to grab all markers individually and do some transformations and calculations on them. I do have access to the source map, and my script is working without any trouble if I download the KML file, place it on the server and open it like any xml file, the problem is getting it programmatically from the source map using the URL. As described, it doesn't link directly to a created KML file that I can read, but rather attaches it to the content-distribution for manual download. Hope thatclarifies

Comment: `Hope that clarifies ` Not really.  I maintain the [geoxml3 third party KML parser for the Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/).  If you can provide a public link to any of the KML you need to access I might be able to parse it.  KmlLayer does render the marker as tiles on the map, so you can't access any of the information directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) and [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) are third party KML parsers for the Google Maps API v3.  Both retrieve KML via javascript and render it on Google Maps API v3 maps as native Google Maps API v3 objects.  Both are subject to the same-domain XmlHttpRequest object security restriction, but that can be overcome by using a proxy.

Example rendering a Google Maps "My Places" KML with geoxml3 (through a proxy):

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fauthuser%3D0%26vps%3D1%26ie%3DUTF8%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D207980401364810598110.0004ab78bf6d3aeea442f

Your KML:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.nl%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fie%3DUTF8%26authuser%3D0%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D211591338385347280942.0004d68aa8ea9e70e23f8

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as far as I can see that example also grabs the file from a local server / filesystem using:  
    if (filename != "TrashDays40.xml") a += "&filename="+filename;
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="' +a+ '">Link to this page<\/a>';

 or can you explain how that link works and if it can be an external google map? Thanks!

Comment: No it doesn't.  It is rendering the KML from  [maps.google.com](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fauthuser%3D0%26vps%3D1%26ie%3DUTF8%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D207980401364810598110.0004ab78bf6d3aeea442f&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=m&z=9), compare to [TrashDays40.xml on Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FTrashDays40.xml&hl=en&sll=44.854845,14.409714&sspn=1.166276,1.766052&t=m&z=9)

Comment: Ah so thats basically the opposite then? You create the TrashDays40.xml file and Google maps can then read it? I need it the other way around, the markers etc are placed on a map at maps.google.com and my script needs to grab that data and process it. Is there any way of doing it without the geoxml3 library?

Comment: No. that is not what I said.  Please look at the links.  The one in the question displays the KML from google.maps.com on a Google Maps API v3 map located on geocodezip.com.  The TrashDays40.xml is the default file and is not relevant to this discussion.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the code. Is there any way that you know of where this is possible without using the geoxml3 (or any other) lib? If possible Id like to stick to just using the google-maps-api-v3

Comment: Of course it is possible, the example posted does it.  You just have to write the code to do it.  The reason libraries like geoxml3 exist is so you don't have to re-invent the wheel.  Feel free to look at the source.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I've been trying to make your example work, but for some reason when I pass my map as parameter "http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https://maps.google.nl/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&authuser=0&msa=0&output=kml&msid=211591338385347280942.0004d68aa8ea9e70e23f8" it returns a "Could not connect to server" error, and your script returns an INVALID_DOCUMENT error. Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: I can't see that link very well in the comments.  Updated my answer with a working link to it.

Comment: Thanks! are you using a premade XML proxy (I can see its on your own site) and if so can I aquire it somewhere? :)